# How do I avoid for my framework consumers to have to put the Spring @Conditional annotation?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a framework where all objects with a certain framework annotation have to be considered to also have the `@Conditional` Spring annotation to work. I would rather abstract Spring and also simplify the API for my consumers. For example, my consumer has classes `FooOne` and `FooTwo` which have annotation `Bar` - I want `FooOne` and `FooTwo` to automatically be considered to have a `@Conditional(Baz.class)` annotation.

```
@Bar("blahblah")
@Conditional(Baz.class) // I want this to be implicit
public class FooOne {
    // stuff
}

@Bar("blahblahblah")
@Conditional(Baz.class) // I want this to be implicit
public class FooTwo {
    // stuff
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Configuration
//@Conditional(Baz.class) - see second bullet below
public @interface Bar {
    // stuff
}

public class Baz implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        Map<String,Object> barMetaData = annotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes("Bar");
        // do stuff
        return something;
    }
}
```

I had two ideas:

- Add the `@Conditional` annotation on a base class (`BaseBar`) and my framework consumers (`FooOne`, `FooTwo`) should inherit from the base class. But the `@Conditional` annotation is not inherited (as specified in the JavaDoc) so Spring won't bother reading the `@Conditional` annotation on the base class.
- Use the `@Conditional` annotation as a meta-annotation on one of my existing annotations (e.g. `Bar`) applied to this class. In this case, Spring is reading the `@Conditional` annotation but the `AnnotatedTypeMetaData` passed into the `Condition` now represents the (meta-)annotations on the annotation (`Bar`) rather than on the class itself (`FooOne`, `FooTwo`). This is not helpful to me as I need to read the actual class annotations within the `Condition` (reading the metadata of `Bar` within `Baz`).

Is there any way to get around this - any other options available? For example, is there any way to get access to those class annotations when `@Conditional` is used as a meta-annotation? Or is there any way to wrap `@Conditional` to make it inherited? Or any way to extend Spring's `@Conditional`-resolving code to make it more suitable for this use-case?